# Compute all bivariate polynomials over GF(2) of degree d or less and evaluate them at certain polynomial input

Tags: evaluation, polynomials, finite-fields

I want to compute all $<=d$ degree bivariate polynomials of form $f_1(x)g_1(y) + f_2(x)g_2(y)$, over field $GF(2)$, and evaluate them at a certain polynomial input

for eg $d = 1$, evaluation at $(p^2, p^3 + 1)$ we get all results as follows

$0 \rightarrow 0$

$1 \rightarrow 1$

$x \rightarrow p^2$

$x + 1 \rightarrow p^2 + 1$

$y \rightarrow p^3 + 1$

$y + 1 \rightarrow p^3$

$x + y \rightarrow p^2 + p^3 + 1$

$x + y + 1 \rightarrow p^2 + p^3$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about efficiency, here is one way:

```
uni[d_, x_] := FromDigits[#, x] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, d + 1]

uni[1, x]
(* {0, 1, x, 1 + x} *)

biv[d_, x_, y_] := 
 Union[Flatten[
   Table[Expand[f1 g1 + f2 g2, Modulus -> 2], {k, 0, d}, {l, 0, 
     d}, {f1, uni[k, x]}, {g1, uni[d - k, y]}, {f2, uni[l, x]}, {g2, 
     uni[d - l, y]}]]]

biv[1, x, y]
(* {0, 1, x, 1 + x, y, 1 + y, x + y, 1 + x + y} *)

biv[1, p^2, p^3 + 1]
(* {0, 1, p^2, p^3, 1 + p^2, 1 + p^3, p^2 + p^3, 1 + p^2 + p^3} *)
```

I'm sure that this can be made much more efficient, but if you only care about small values, this will work fine.